# Path to static file in Django - 404

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm completely lost and can't figure out how to configure path to just one css file.
The site structure is:

```
--mysite
 |
 |-/static
    | 
    /styles
        |
       site.css
```

What should I put into STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT to make it work?
And how to link this file? (Currently it's

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'styles/site.css' %}" />
```

)
and

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static/')
```

and mysite.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
    url(r'^mysite/$', mysite)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The error is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/static/styles/site.css
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^hello/$
^mysite/$
^static\/styles\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, mysite/static/styles/site.css, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: what about the `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable?

Comment: I don't use it because I don't know what to put there. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked for me:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/static')
```

Comment: ok, looks like only the slash was missing. I was thinking that also static root is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I change STATIC_URL, the actual url becomes just http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles/site.css and still 404 because the address is wrong now. :(